# Reddening (not sure if this is a error) in XML ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

At the time of writing the XML code, I had a misunderstanding of what was happening, I need to set clear restrictions that only work correctly in Constraint, the problem is that I have several such layouts in my code and for some reason they are highlighted in red, AT THE SAME TIME, IDE (AS) does not swear at them, how to understand this, this is an error or ways of distinguishing between layouts, they say, this is yellow, this is red - you can’t confuse it (I can add to this theory that the main Layout is generally green). Can not understand..

What bothers me is the fact that on the XML markup everything can be normal and show without errors that, in fact, this is the case, but on an external drive/emulator everything can be different (I haven’t run it, there are still problems with this, for some reason reasons.)

Here is my XML code. Don’t look at the mistakes, I didn’t set any restrictions, I’m in the process, I just don’t want to sit and do it for a long time only to have it turn out that it won’t work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="844dp"
    android:background="@color/purplebg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/user_profil"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Usernane"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.048"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.523" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_profil"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="119dp"
            android:text="2,343"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.866"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/num1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="193dp"
            android:text="Posts"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="191dp"
            android:text="2,423"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
            android:text="Followers"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView17"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
            android:text="Following"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView19"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:text="8,983"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.857"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView20"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="288dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profilepic2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/username_an"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="195dp"
        android:background="@color/Black5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_profil">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            android:text="Followed by username, username&#xA;and 100 others"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Username"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="SubUserName"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            android:text="Discription"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
            android:text="Linktree"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_compone"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="325dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_compone"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="200dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="325dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eCaE.png)

I tried to work in Relative, but I can’t do what I want to do, I’m starting to think that if this is a mistake, I’ll optimize the XML code and do all the work as a background and then stupidly insert text and buttons.